# Save and read data from Azure database to Windows 8 app

Tags: sql, database, azure, windows-8, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure database instance and a windows 8 app which is running on an ARM device. I need to connect to the Azure database and save data into the database and retrieve some of the fields of the database. I know that I can connect the database using Azure Mobile Services but the tutorial only shows how to read data. Is there any way in which I can save data into the database too?

I basically have a sales table and I would like to have the user save his sales into the table  and read (and display) the rows which match his username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the tutorial actually shows how to save data as well - ToDo list items.  In [Step 8 below where this link takes you](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-dotnet/#header-3) you'll see a call to `InsertAsync` which in turn fires off the associated script.  Or if you worked with the demo app you can set up from the Windows Azure portal, you'll see code like this:

```
    private async void InsertTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)
    {
        // This code inserts a new TodoItem into the database. When the operation completes
        // and Mobile Services has assigned an Id, the item is added to the CollectionView
        await todoTable.InsertAsync(todoItem);
        items.Add(todoItem);                        
    }

    ...

    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var todoItem = new TodoItem { Text = TextInput.Text };
        InsertTodoItem(todoItem);
    }
```

Then in the Windows Azure portal if you need to do any manipulation of the object before it goes into the database, you can do that with node.js scripting.  For example, the image below shows how to replace whatever the `Text` of the `TodoItem` was set to in code with the hard coded "replaced text," illustrative but not very useful :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I might be asking something silly here but would you happen to know how to display the database items in a List View in XAML?

Comment: take a look at the sample ToDo app for Windows 8 (you can download the complete app when you create a new Windows Azure Mobile Service).  It uses data binding to show the list of items in the database (after you add a few items of course)

Comment: I have followed the example and I am using the following code:

var table = App.MobileService.GetTable<UserTransactions>();
            var tableView = await table.Where(t => t.Account == "account").ToCollectionView();

 TransactionsView.ItemsSource = tableView; 

However, instead of the data in the table, I am getting: ProjectName.UserTransactions for 4 times (which is the number of records in the table). Any idea how I can display the actual data in the table instead?

Comment: You need to set up a DataTemplate in your ListView with individual controls that display each element of the data, and then bind the content of those controls to individual fields of UserTransactions... e.g.   <TextBox Text={Binding ItemText} />  where ItemText is a field of UserTransactions (not sure if it really is :))  The list/collection of UserTransactions should be the ItemsSource property for that ListView

Comment: Thanks - quite silly of me to forget this.

With regards to the insert script as shown in the picture you sent, I am trying to add a script where the user can insert data from one database table into another. The tables are in different schemas. I only need to insert a particular column into another particular field - the amount obtained on insertion into the field 'Balance' of a particular user. I have tried the following script but nothing happens. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23509610/script.txt